# Calculate object rotation angle from mouse movement in OpenGL drawing in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, rotation

In the [Qt 5.9 Qt OpenGL Hello GL2 Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-hellogl2-glwidget-cpp.html), to implement the rotation of the objects, there is a degree normalization function when calculate the rotation from the movement of the mouse. I just don't get it 1) why it needs dx and dy time 8 to get the mouse movement distance? and 2) then 360 times 16 here to normalize the angle, why 16? And 3) when set up the rotation in render by dividing 16? Thanks.

```
void GLWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    int dx = event->x() - m_lastPos.x();
    int dy = event->y() - m_lastPos.y();

    if (event->buttons() & Qt::RightButton) {
        ....
        setZRotation(m_zRot + 8 * dx);
    }
    m_lastPos = event->pos();
}

static void qNormalizeAngle(int &angle) {
    while (angle < 0)
        angle += 360 * 16;
    while (angle > 360 * 16)
        angle -= 360 * 16;
}

void GLWidget::setZRotation(int angle)
{
    qNormalizeAngle(angle);
    if (angle != m_zRot) {
        m_zRot = angle;
        .....
        update();
    }
}

void GLWidget::paintGL() {
    ....
    m_world.rotate(m_zRot / 16.0f, 0, 0, 1);
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything about the code in question smells like someone who simply had no real idea what they're doing.

The *effect* of what they've done is this. They scaled the input angle by 8, relative to the mouse delta. This causes the eventual angle to be 8x larger. But then they divide this angle by 16 before getting matrices with it. Therefore, the effect of what they've done is scale the input angle by 0.5.

The clamping to the range [0, 360 * 16] is just a part of that nonsense. They're *really* clamping to [0, 360], just in a really obtuse and insane way.

Overall, I'd say you should avoid Qt's example code like the plague.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that they are just trying to keep more precision in the rotation as the variables are integers in the example. dividing them back with floats could result in smoother rotation.
By multiplying up the mouse dx is just make it more sensitive - kind of easier to turn it around.
I think this is not so bad example anyways.